# When a word is both a common and proper noun, how do you use it as a cultural modifier?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns, cultural-phrases, cultural-correctness

I am writing a piece on Kandi Kids, the name for a specific rave culture.

> "The Kandi Kid community..." (Proper noun.)
>
> "She gave him a piece of kandi." (Common noun.)
>
> "They saw two young Kandi Girls." (Capitalized? Or is it Kandi girls?)

Thank you.

Comment: Why is "kandi kids" a proper noun and "rave" isn't?

Comment: Once we capitalise those other important words "Community" and "Culture" and "Piece" this is almost German.

Comment: @DavidK - I don't know. It just felt correct. I can't find "rave culture" capitalized anywhere. Should they both be? Or should they both me uncapitalized?

Comment: I'm starting to think it's all uncapitalized. I found some old articles on the culture and they called them kandi kids. If I am introducing them in a book, should I put them in italics or quotes, or leave the term as-is?

Comment: An analogy for Kandi Kids would be Alt-Right which, when googled, has articles that capitalize it and articles that do not.

Comment: Another, possibly more well known example would be "Muslim Brotherhood". You capitalize it because it's a specific, named group, but if you knew some brothers who were Muslim, you'd write "Muslim brothers".

Comment: What you're finding seems consistent with the answer that has been posted. I'd go with whatever works best in the context of your piece (which I'm guessing uses these words multiple times).

Comment: Yes, I agree. Sometimes it is frustrating when consistency is the answer versus some rule set in stone. This was my first question on the site and someone downvoted me to a negative number. Is that going to hurt my ability to contribute to the site? Thanks, and my apologies as I could have phrased the question better.

Answer (score 2):

Capitalization of groups and communities is open to different approaches. However once you have decided Kandi Kids is a proper noun, you should also capitalize all words referring to it - " The Kandi Kid community". This is just like the difference between democrat and Democrat.

A girl who is part of this should be a Kandi girl, implying that she is a girl (common noun) who is a member of the Kandi (proper noun) communit. However if you have decided that Kandi Girls is also the name of a specific community it is Kandi Girl, implying that she is a member of the Kandi Girl community.

Comment: Great answer. I suppose this is a matter of consistency and interpretation which reflects in the articles I'm finding on the subject.